# problema con selector con espacio, selenium python

Tags: html, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

tengo un problema con los selectorer, que tienen un espacio al inicio:

tengo en html algo como esto:

```
    <div class=" _xyz"></div>
```

y en python hago esto:

```
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name(' _xyz')
```

o esto otro:

```
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name(' _xyz')
```

El resultado es selenium diciendo que no localiza al elemento.
¿como selecciono elementos que tiene un espacio al principio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente los espacios no son un problema para los selectores. Como alternativa podrias intentar utilizar una busqueda por xpath con la funcion `normalize_spaces`

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[normalize-space(@class)='_xyz']")
```

Comment: Me informa de expresión ilegal :(

Comment: Editada la funcion, que tenia un error.

Comment: funciona perfecto